# "error message" with lambda handler in aws lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda

Hi I am learning how to use AWS lambda functions and I don't understand how to use the lambda handler. When I use this function in the results I get the expected return in function logs.

```
import boto3


session = boto3.Session( 
    aws_access_key_id='XXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
    aws_secret_access_key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')

                    #Then use the session to get the resource
s3 = session.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('XXXXX')
for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
    print(my_bucket_object.key)
```

But when I added the lambda_handler doesn't work

```
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    session = boto3.Session( 
        aws_access_key_id='XXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
        aws_secret_access_key='XXXXXXXXXXXX')
    
                        #Then use the session to get the resource
    s3 = session.resource('s3')
    my_bucket = s3.Bucket('XXXXXX')
    for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
        print(my_bucket_object.key)
```

For this case I received as response

{
"errorMessage": "2022-05-10T14:50:10.023Z a840a005-9af0-4827-919a-7e2bd7eb0aae Task timed out after 3.02 seconds"
}

If anyone has knowledge of what I am doing wrong I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this without any security settings on a S3 bucket that you make public for testing purposes.  You can then run/test this from you local machine to help you with debugging before you deploy it.

```
def list_file_in_bucket(event, context):
    bucket_name = event['bucket_name']
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    my_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
    for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
        print(my_bucket_object.key)
```

Tested with

```
def test_s3():
    test_bucket = 'public-test-bucket'
    event = {}
    event['bucket_name'] = test_bucket
    function.list_file_in_bucket(event, {})
    assert True == False
```

Obviously you want to change the assert.